# Memory leak when create std::shared_ptr to assign member variable

Tags: c++, memory-leaks

Here is a one example class.

```
class Test {
private:
    std::shared_ptr<int> m_iTest;
    void testLoop(void);
};


void Test::testLoop(void)
{
    for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++)
       m_iTest = std::make_shared<int>;
}
```

In this code, when called testLoop function, allocate new int type memory and assigned to m_iTest member variable. The first loop (i=0), create new memory and assigned to m_iTest. And the second loop (i=1), create new memory and assigend to m_iTest.........Hm??? What about the first created memory? Is it deleted or not? And the third loop (i=2), create new memory and assigned to m_iTest....Hm..???

So, I think this code occurs memory leak, right? Or shared_ptr can be deleted automatically?

(It's just sample code. not about use vector or any...)

Comment: You can find out yourself: Try using a class of your own instead of an int as the pointed to type. Write its destructor so that it outputs a message or something you can observe. Then run it and see what happens.

Comment: Thanks, TheUndeadFish! :-)

Answer (score 3):

When you assign to a `std::shared_ptr`, the reference count for the previously managed object (if there was one) goes down by 1. So in your loop, when you call `make_shared` the first time, you create a new object with a reference count of 1. When you call it the second time, you create another object with a reference count of 1, and the reference count for the previous object goes down to 0, causing it to be deleted.

So no, there is no memory leak. If there was, it would be a poorly designed "smart" pointer.

Comment: Thanks, Benjamin Lindley. In this code, created 5 object and m_iTest point to last object when finished loop. So, each object has 1 reference count, but not used, only last object can be used. When the class deleted, the last object's reference count (pointed m_iTest) goes down to 0, and then deleted. But, the other 4 object still has 1 reference count. I think 4 object can not be deleted. Right?

Comment: @je-woong.ku: No. The other objects are deleted as soon as the `shared_ptr` is assigned to in the next iteration of the loop, because their reference count goes to 0. **All the objects are correctly deleted, there are no memory leaks in the code.** (was my answer not clear on that?)

Comment: Oh! I See. I understand your comment. "and the reference count for the previous object goes down to 0, causing it to be deleted." the PREVIOUS OBJECT goes down to 0..I really appreciate you !